# Wordpress Help (WPForms + PayPal Workflow)

Tags: wordpress, forms, paypal

CONTEXT:
I’ve used the WPForms plugin in Wordpress to create a custom donation form for my client. The client wants to accept donations via PayPal.

PROBLEM:
WPForms has a PayPal add-on feature but it costs $200.

QUESTION
To avoid paying $200 for the expensive plugin, how can I manually direct/post the WPForm data entered by the user (name, email, address, donation amount, and employment info) to PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

In the example code you’ll see below, we’re first checking the form ID to make sure it matches the form that’s being targeted. Then we’re checking a specific field (by the field ID) to see if it’s empty.

Just remember to change the form ID from 5 to match your form ID and change the '4' to match your field ID.

```
function wpf_dev_process( $fields, $entry, $form_data ) {

    // Optional, you can limit to specific forms. Below, we restrict output to
    // form #5.
    if ( absint( $form_data['id'] ) !== 5 ) {
        return $fields;
    }

    // check the field ID 4 to see if it's empty and if it is, run the error    
    if(empty($fields[4]['value'])) 
        {
            // Add to global errors. This will stop form entry from being saved to the database.
            // Uncomment the line below if you need to display the error above the form.
            // wpforms()->process->errors[ $form_data['id'] ]['header'] = esc_html__( 'Some error occurred.', 'plugin-domain' );    

            // Check the field ID 4 and show error message at the top of form and under the specific field
               wpforms()->process->errors[ $form_data['id'] ] [ '4' ] = esc_html__( 'Some error occurred.', 'plugin-domain' );

            // Add additional logic (what to do if error is not displayed)
        }
    }
add_action( 'wpforms_process', 'wpf_dev_process', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks, Sanjeev!  Where do I place this code?  In which file?  Also, what does “10” and “3” represent in your code?

Comment: You need to place the function in theme's functions.php and call the function where you want to get the form values. 10 or 3 is the WPForm id.